# Column headers are not appearing on each page in an exported report

Tags: reporting-services

On my SRS report my column headers are not showing up on each new page when the report is exported. They were originally not even repeating in the preview mode, so in the grouping pane I set it to [Advanced Mode], then for both (Static) groups i updated the settings **KeepWithGroup=true** and **RepeatOnNewPage=true**. That made the column headers show up on each page in the preview mode. However, when I **Export > PDF** the column headers are not showing up on the new pages, just the first page.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Makolyte

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: SSRS 2008 R2. 

This is actually working now, and I'm not sure *why*.